# 2 count по одному столбцу с разными условиями sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

у меня есть такой запрос

```
    SELECT name_book, yers, name_publisher,count(copy_book.id_book)as cnt_a FROM book
    left join  publishing_house
    ON book.id_publisher = publishing_house.id_publisher
    left join copy_book
    on book.id_book = copy_book.id_book 
    group by book.id_book
```

Который добавляет столбец общего количества.
Как мне добавить еще один столбец суммы с таким условием

```
on book.id_book = copy_book.id_book and availability_in_library=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условное агрегирование называется.

```sql
SELECT name_book, 
       yers, 
       name_publisher,
       count(copy_book.id_book)as cnt_a,
       SUM(availability_in_library=1) AS cnt_b
FROM book
left join  publishing_house ON book.id_publisher = publishing_house.id_publisher
left join copy_book on book.id_book = copy_book.id_book 
group by book.id_book
```

Comment: спасибо, буду знать!